# Algolia Wordpress Plugin: Index Result From Vimeography Pro Plugin

Tags: vimeo, algolia

Is there a way to index results from Vimeography Pro Wordpress Plugin using Algolia Search?

Answer (score 0):

The Algolia plugin for WordPress allows you to index any post type.

If the Vimeography Pro uses custom post types, you will be able to index them. If it introduces custom attributes, you will need to push those by using hooks.

You'll find more details about how to extend the Algolia plugin in the official documentation here: https://community.algolia.com/wordpress